# Rails server not loading static images despite 'config.serve_static_assets = true'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, puma

I'm running a rails app which serves some small images statically (like the site logo and background texture). I'm storing these images in `/public/images/`. Everything has been working fine until recently, but now suddenly the server is responding with a 404 for these image requests.

The images are stored in the right place, and the front-end is requesting the right thing (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/images/logo.png`), but still the 404. I also have set `config.serve_static_assets = true` in development.rb and tried `rake assets:clean` and `rake assets:clobber`, and deleted the contents of `/tmp/cache/`. I think the problem is linked to me running `rake assets:precompile` locally, but I'm unsure of the exact reason/solution.

Interestingly, although all image requests return a 404, requests to images which actually exist get a 404 with a message displayed to the user ("File not found: /Users/*user*/Documents/*app name*/public/images/logo.png"), whereas requests for images that genuinely don't exist like /images/foobar.png just return a routing error.

Answer (score 0):

Try with including it you gem file if you don't have it before. Thanks

```
gem "non-stupid-digest-assets"
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't fix the issue :(